# Issues with minpointlength & datalabels overlap in columnrange

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to add minpointlength property in the column range chart. The reason I am adding because for smaller values chart width is too small and in order to adjust it along with the data label, I am adding minpointlength. Few issues I am facing

1. By adding minpointlength chart division is not starting from 0
2. DataLabels are getting overlap. It should never overlap and always align in the center.

So, far I tried these things from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168917/set-minpointlength-for-one-of-two-series-in-highchart)

```
series: [{
    minPointLength: 80,
    data: [...]
}, {
    data: [...]
}]
```

2. I tried to calculate dynamically using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821351/highcharts-set-minimum-height-for-stacked-column-chart)

   events: {
   load: function() {

   ```
        var chart = this,
          minColHeightVal = 50;

        chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
          s.points.forEach(function(p) {

            if (p.y < minColHeightVal) {
              p.update({
                y: minColHeightVal,
                realValue: p.y
              }, false);
            }
          });
        });

        chart.redraw();

      }
    }
   ```
3. From the  [github](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/xkbz6mrs/)

   ```
    (function (H) {

    H.seriesTypes.columnrange.prototype.modifyValue = function (val) {
        var minPointVal = this.options.minPointVal;
        if (minPointVal) {
            if (val >= 0 && val < minPointVal) {
                return minPointVal;
            } else if (val < 0 && val > -minPointVal) {
                return -minPointVal;
            }
        }
        return val;
    };


    // Modify the values used in stacks. If impemented in the core, just do this
    // inline where y = yData[i] is set.
    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'setStackedPoints', function (proceed) {

        var yData = this.processedYData,
            i = this.processedYData.length;
        while(i--) {
            if (this.modifyValue) {
                yData[i] = this.modifyValue(yData[i]);
            }
        }
        proceed.call(this);
    });
   ```

   }(Highcharts));

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/0esr6259/3/)

**Highchart Version: 7.0.1**

Comment: I cannot see the `dataLabels` overlapping issue. I tried to resize the window many times but seems fine to me. Could you attach the screenshot? About using the `minpointlength` - could you join to the conversation, share your case and ask for the workaround in the GH issue? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1776

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I will add my case in this Github issue